# How can I create a map with every two items in a list in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to create a map that takes two values from a list and uses the first value as the key and the second key as the value but I can't figure out how to do it.

Let's say I have a list like the following.

`-e`, `normal`, `-t`, `flat`, `-s`, `test`

How can I create a map from that list that looks like the following?

`-e` to `normal`, `-t` to `flat`, `-s` to `test`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to use built in functions, [`chunked`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html) can be a quick way to do this:

```
val arguments = listOf("-e", "normal", "-t", "flat", "-s", "test")

val map: Map<String, String> = arguments
        .chunked(2) { (switch, value) -> switch to value }
        .toMap()

println(map) // {-e=normal, -t=flat, -s=test}
```

Answer (score -2):

Using *stdlib*, `zipWithNext()` is the most straightforward way to achieve your goal:

```
val arguments = listOf("-e", "normal", "-t", "flat", "-s", "test")

val map = arguments.zipWithNext().toMap()
```

It's available starting from Kotlin 1.2.

Comment: This is wrong, result would be: `{-e=normal, normal=-t, -t=flat, flat=-s, -s=test}`. `zipWithNext` works for each two elements, so it will zip first and second, then second and third, then third and fourth, ...
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip-with-next.html

Comment: Yep, you're obviously right... Sorry for the misleading answer